# How do I hyperlapse a video file on Windows?

Tags: windows, video-editing

Hyperlapse is a somewhat recently developed timelapsing technique that removes jitters.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what exactly do you want to ask?

Comment: [Microsoft Gets the Jitters Out of Time-Lapse Video](http://www.technewsworld.com/story/80878.html) (Aug 13, 2014): There are a number of ways Microsoft could commercialize Hyperlapse. It could license the technology to others -- for example, an action-cam maker could bundle it with software for its product -- or it could incorporate it into its existing platforms. // "Microsoft may commercialize the technology as a Windows app," said Ross Rubin, principal analyst at Reticle Research. --- This suggests that it's not commercially available yet.

Comment: Is it unclear because you're not aware of what hyperlapsing is? I'm not sure what part is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how is to transfer the video file to an iPhone, and use the Youtube Capture app to "stabalize". I am still not sure if this is the same technique outlined in Microsoft's white paper. Instagram has a hyperlapse app, but as of March 6th 2015, it will not read in an existing Video file.